# MySQL Versioning bring all schemas to the same baseline

Tags: mysql, versioning

So, I'm introducing Flyway into our environment to have all schema changes in version control, so I can automate any changes.

The issue is that I have multiple DBs (let's say 30) that all have different versions of the schemas. I'm looking for a tool that would help me bring everything to a common baseline, eg. compare tables and do the necessary alters. The differences are not big - mainly missing columns and indexes.

Comment: Re-ask this on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what I have figured out is that I can do a full baseline update with Liquibase:

1. Create an updatefile from gold database image
2. Append a skip on fail tag to all the changes in the updatefile
3. Script a run on all databases, credentials from file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do this once you can try MySQL Workbench. Just import the Schema from your "golden image"-database and synchronize it down to all other databases.
Maybe you'll want to run a diff & report before doing that.

Comment: I think this would work fine, although I think it would take some manual work to complete. Thanks.